# How are these sets equal? (ELI5)

Tags: python

Looking to create a function that checks if the input string is a pangram. However, I am not too sure why this works. From my amateur perspective it appears that if the alphaset equaled the string it could still be a pangram so wouldn't it just be less than not less than or equal too? Thanks.

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    alphaset = set(alphabet)  
    return alphaset <= set(str1.lower())
```

Comment: If it is `==` then your function returns `True`, which is what you want, no? It is basically stating return whether or not the entire alphabet is a subset of the characters in your string... So it can be equal, in which case it uses all and only those letter in the alphabet, or less than, in which case it uses all the letters, but perhaps some extra characters (punctuation)

Comment: have you printed out the different values/parameters? Sometimes it can be useful to visualize what is happening

Answer (score 1):

From our friends at Wikipedia:

> A pangram or holoalphabetic sentence is a sentence using every letter of a given alphabet at least once

If you reuse a letter, duplicates will certainly be removed in the `set()` call. Since you might have other characters, such as punctuation, it's possible for `set(str1)` to be longer than `alphaset`. The `str.lower()` function does not remove the punctuation, it just converts uppercase letters to lowercase.

```
>>> "HELLO_WORLD".lower()
hello_world
```

And the `set()` operator will remove the duplicate `l`s and `o`s. We also see the underscore remain.

```
>>> set("HELLO_WORLD".lower())
set(['e', 'd', 'h', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w', '_'])
```

As for the comparison, the `set.__le__` method only returns true if all the values on the left set are within the set on the right.

```
>>> bool(set(['a', 'b', 'c']) <= set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
True
>>> bool(set(['a', 'b', 'c']) <= set(['a', 'b', 'c']))
True
>>> bool(set(['a', 'b', 'c']) <= set(['a', 'b']))
False
>>> bool(set(['a', 'b', 'c']) <= set(['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']))
False
>>> bool(set(['a', 'b', 'c']) < set(['a', 'b', 'c']))
False
```

So, in the end, `alphaset <= set(str1.lower())` which check if every character is within `str1.lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

This was a helpful question for me to understand sets better, so thank you for this OP.  Here's a bit of a console dump:

```
>>> full_set = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> partial_set = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> over_set = set([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

`partial_set < full_set` is True, and `over_set > full_set` is also True. The `>` operator will return True if there are elements in the first set that are not in the second, and the `<` operator will return True if there are elements in the second set that are not in the first. `==` will be "these sets contain the same elements".

`>=` tells us that the first set must contain all elements in the second, but may *also* have elements that aren't (say, a number).  To check for a pangram, all we need to do is take the string we want to check, lowercase it with `str.lower()` (because we're using `string.ascii_lowercase`), put both arrays into sets, and compare them.

```
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

`set(mystr.lower()) >= set(string.ascii_lowercase)` will return True as long as all letters of the alphabet are in it, regardless of spaces or other characters. Tbh, I think it was more confusing to have it written inversely, as `set(string.ascii_lowercase) <= set(mystr.lower())` - when I first looked at it, I had no idea what was going on either.